# Azure search - Searching for a phrase

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Search within a .Net application to search across several fields over multiple documents.  When searching for a phrase by quoting the search keyword (for example "software developer"), the results include those that seem only to contain the word "software", ahead of those with the phrase "software developer".  Are we misunderstanding how phrase searching should work?

I am using SearchMode.All and QueryType.Full

I am not supplying any filters in this case

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using to build the search text that you're sending to the Search/SearchAsync method?

Comment: Or just final url/request when accessing Azure Search API?